# Isotope : Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method 'filter' upon append / addItems

Tags: jquery, filter, append, jquery-isotope

Keep getting this error whenever I appended to my isotope. Changed appended to addItems and it seems to work better now but still throws this error randomly.

Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'filter' jquery.isotope.min.js:13

```
$.get('feedAJAX.php?from='+ajaxFrom, function (data) {                         
    try{var $newItems = $(data);}catch(err){var $newItems = '';}

    try{
        $('#container').append( $newItems ).isotope( 'addItems', $newItems );
        } catch(err) {
        // just in case there is a time delay in loading new items - retry again
        setTimeout(function(){
            resetIso();
            $('#container').append( $newItems ).isotope( 'addItems', $newItems);        
        },3000);
    }

    resetIso();
    setTimeout(function(){ resetIso(); },1000);
});
```